# Any default AWS policy to prune the old AMIs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ami

Does AWS provide any default/custom policy to prune/delete old AMIs based on certain criteria/filter?

Have gone through docs but did not find it.

Comment: There is https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/snapshot-lifecycle.html

Answer (score -2):

Retention type can be used to prune old AMI's.You can retain AMIs based on either their total count or their age. Steps to automate AMI lifecyles are provided in the below page,
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ami-policy.html